# Ionic 2: Get index of each item in list and store it into Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2, angularfire2

I am currently developing an Ionic 2 Mobile Application. I have a list of items that I get from my Firebase using AngularFire2. I implemented a reorder function on the list. I would like to be able to store the index of the items in the lists and send it to my Firebase so that I can use the index to prioritise the items based on the user's preferences. Is there a way where I can do this? I tried to send 'indexes' to my Firebase but it didnt work.

HTML:

```
      <ion-list reorder="true" (ionItemReorder)="reorderItems($event)">
        <ion-item *ngFor="let item of categories; let i = index;">
          {{i+1}}. {{item.name}}
        </ion-item>

      </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
```

Typescript:

```
     export class ManageFavouritesPage {
      fireAuth: any;
      items: any;
      categories: any;
      categorykey: any;

      constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public af: AngularFire, private toastCtrl: ToastController, public authData: AuthData) {

        let userid = this.authData.getID();
        this.items = af.database.list(`/users/${userid}/favourites`)
          .subscribe(data => this.categories = data)  
      }


      reorderItems(indexes) {
        let element = this.categories[indexes.from];
        let element2 = this.categories[indexes.to].$key;
        this.categories.splice(indexes.from, 1);
        this.categories.splice(indexes.to, 0, element);
        let userid = this.authData.getID();
        this.items = this.af.database.object(`users/${userid}/favourites/${element2}`).update( {priority: indexes.to});

     }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

The indices of all elements between `from` and `to` will have changed. You can use a multi-location `update` call to update all of them at once:

```ts
reorderItems(indexes) {

  // Reorder the array:

  this.categories.splice(indexes.from, 1);
  this.categories.splice(indexes.to, 0, element);

  // Build the multi-location update:

  let min = Math.min(indexes.from, indexes.to);
  let max = Math.max(indexes.from, indexes.to);

  let reindexed = {};
  for (let i = min; i <= max; ++i) {
    reindexed[`${this.categories[i].$key}/priority`] = i;
  }

  // Update the reordered elements:

  let userid = this.authData.getID();
  this.af.database.object(`users/${userid}/favourites`).update(reindexed);
}
```

Also, `this.items` is most likely not what you think it is, as `subscribe` returns an RxJS subscription and `update` returns a promise.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Apparently it does update the priority in the Firebase. However, I found out that it only works half of the time. Sometimes when I rearrange the items it will revert back to the first order.

Comment: Reordering before the update completes could get wierd. `update` returns a promise; you shouldn't re-reorder until it's resolved, but whether Ionic let's you enforce that is another matter.

Comment: Alright! Adding an Edit/Done button might work? It will only update once I clicked on the Done button.